# How to send ExceptionNotifier from a queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

Say I rescue from an Exception and I do:

```
 begin
      raise StandardError 
    rescue StandardError => ex
      ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(ex)
    end
 end
```

How can I make that ExceptionNotifier email be sent from a queue? So, it is asynchronous to the process of the application?

In the docs I can see how to send ExceptionNotifier if the error has happened within a worker, but not how to enqueue that sending to a queue.

Answer (score 0):

The queue aspect of Rails *has* to be handled by a third-party semi-persistent data store. We use [`Redis`](http://redis.io) & [`Resque`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque)

--

Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-redis-with-rails/) on this:

**Initializer**

```
#app/config/initializers/redis.rb
require 'resque/server' #-> allows processing of jobs
require 'resque_scheduler' #-> allows for scheduling

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"] ||= "http://localhost:6379")
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

-

**Resque**

This will allow you to send data to `redis`, using your `Resque` queue to handle it:

```
def your_action
    Resque.enqueue(SendEmail, [[data ref]])
end
```

-

**Queue**

Then you can use `resque` to run through the `Redis` queue & send the emails:

```
$ rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

Quite a vague description, I know; but hopefully it will give you an idea as to how to use a third-party queue-based system to handle sending emails for you

Comment: Yes, but how do I specifically enqueue that Notifier inside one of the queues? I am using Sidekiq.